# html <li> tag won't expand to wrap anchor padding

Tags: html, css

I have the following navbar on my page, and would like the `<li>` tags to expand their height to the height of my anchors, but for some reason they ignore the anchors padding (you can see this if you run the snippet and mouseover the menu items).

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Thanks

```css
#navbar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #913D88;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #navbar {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
#navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar ul li {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  #navbar ul li {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
#navbar ul li a {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #navbar ul li a {
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
  }
}
#navbar ul li a:visited, #navbar ul li a:link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #c371ba;
  color: #491f45;
}
#navbar ul li a img {
  height: 1em;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown:hover > .drop-nav {
  display: block;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  display: none;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav li {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: block;
  background-color: #913D88;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav li:hover {
  color: #491f45;
  background-color: #c371ba;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav a {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav a:visited, #navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav alink {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" ng-controller="NavbarController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-click="goTo('http://www.ijs.si/ijsw')"><a href="">IJS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">knjižnica&nbsp;<span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></a>
      <ul class="drop-nav">
        <li ng-click="goTo('#/predstavitev')"><a href="">predstavitev</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">osebje</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">zaloga&nbsp;<span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></a>
      <ul class="drop-nav">
        <li><a href="">tiskane revije</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">elektronske revije</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">baze podatkov</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-click="goTo('http://www.cobiss.si/scripts/cobiss?command=CONNECT&amp;base=50108')"><a href="">katalog (COBISS)</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">storitve&nbsp;<span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></a>
      <ul class="drop-nav">
        <li><a href="">medknjižnična izposoja</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">fotokopirnica</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">bibliografije</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img src="images/EN.gif">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: add display:block for #navbar ul li a

Comment: can't believe it was that simple. Write it up as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `display:block` for `#navbar ul li a`

Answer (score 0):

Anchor is `display:inline` by default, which is means that padding wouldn't work. 
Only what you need to do is add `display: block` (or `display:inline-block`) for you anchor.

```
#navbar ul li a {
  display:block;
}
```